# Filling DataTable with DataAdapter and converting one column from string to DateTime type

Tags: c#, windows, forms, sqlite, datatable

I'm using sqlite database which holds next table.

```
car ((int) vin_number, (int) number_plate, (string) name, (string) release_date)
```

What I'm trying to do is to fill DataTable with data from table and later on put it in datagridview in windows forms. This is what I have so far.

```
try
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM car";
    using (SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=car.db;Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;"))
    {
        sqlite_conn.Open();
        using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, sqlite_conn))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            data_grid_item.DataSource = dt;
        }

    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

This works fine. The problem is, that sqlite only support a few data types. Since it also has no suppport for date, I decided to put attribute `release date` as string in format dd/MM/YYYY. Is there a way I can convert it to DateTime object in C# when filling DataTable so that my DataGridView can sort this column properly aswell?

Comment: You can add a column after the Fill() and then convert to string DateTime and put in new column.  dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

Comment: You should also consider using Entity Framework because for SQLite it handles Datetimes by its own

Answer (score 0):

If you want "strong" data-types...you can add a computed aka a calculated column to the data-table.

So when you run the query, some of the things are just gonna be "strings".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=net-6.0

> One use of the Expression property is to create calculated columns.

Pseudo Coding it:

```
DataColumn totalColumn = new DataColumn();
totalColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Date");
totalColumn.ColumnName = "ReleaseDateAsDate";
totalColumn..Expression="Convert(ReleaseDateStringRaw, 'System.Date')"
```

Untested code.

Obviously, that is not considering "nulls" and strings that are not actually dates.  That is a problem whenever people use string-db-columns for primitive data types that are not strings.  (I know you are not doing this on purpose, this is a sqllite limitation in this case)

Side Notes.

Do not use "Select *".  Specify your columns.

SQLiteConnection and MessageBox in the code snipplet.
That means you are not "layering" your application.

I strongly recommend internet-searching for "c# layered architecture"

Comment: Thank you for another solution, even thought I managed to solve it another way. It's my first time building standalone app in c# and I'm trying my best :) I will look into layered architecture aswell - should be smth familiar to MVC model right?